# How to reset .NET Framework's Global Access Cache?

Tags: .net, windows, .net-4.8

i added some Assemblies to .NET Framework's Global Access Cache, for them to be loaded by an app which requires them . i used a not-overwriting command of `gacutil.exe` for this . and then some apps stopped working, 1 of them showed this error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Diagnostics.Process' from assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=<<..>>'.
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CommandLine.Program.MainCore(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CommandLine.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

removing the added content from GAS didn't help .

after installing last version of .NET Framework 4.8 Runtime i started getting this error instead

```
error CS7065: Error building Win32 resources -- Could not load type 'System.Numerics.BigInteger' from assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=<<..>>'.
```

and i also catched this

```
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationResult' from assembly 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=<<..>>'.
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication..ctor(CommandLineApplication parent, IHelpTextGenerator helpTextGenerator, CommandLineContext context)
```

now due to the errors, multiple apps can't run, can anyone please help me fix this ?

Comment: *"multiple apps can't run"* - desktop app or a web app inside IIS? if its IIS, remember to double check the [`machine.config`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions#redirect-versions-at-the-machine-level).

Comment: @BagusTesa i think they are desktop, they are offline, but i don't know how to make sure

Comment: machine.config -s in `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\` don't have the items i added nor anything strange

Comment: may we know the assembly you have added using `gacutil.exe`? personally, adding stuff to GAC is a last resort - i would preferred to have the assemblies live beside the offending app and put bindings in its config files.

Comment: @BagusTesa i tried putting the .dll -s next to the .exe 1st, but the app seemed to not care . it kept showing me that it can't find needed Assembly and docs shown that items in GAS get the highest priority (so can overwrite other references) . i added a relatively long list of .dll -s, so specifics won't give much, that and alot of unnecessary words in documentation made me to not try `<<name>>.exe.config` .

Comment: actually docs wasn't the reason, its just that it seems/ed that i would need to somehow extract name and token of each assembly and put it into a complex text structure, i maybe would do it for 1-5 but not 30 nor write a script for the single run of the app .

Comment: *"i would need to somehow extract name and token of each assembly and put it into a complex text structure"* - err, there are tools for that. Visual Studio for one can handle this for you. but, again what was the assembly you added? by the error it seems standard library (maybe an older version?) being added. at this point, you may need to uninstall all .net version through control panel then do a restart and reinstall them back or have windows update to sort them out.

Comment: i can't uninstall ASP.NET 4.8 , because due to that my Windows Update doesn't work (unrelated to the issue) idk how to get it back, is it included in .NET Framework 4.8 Runtime distributable ? also .NET Framework 3.5 installer doesn't start, so can't reinstall it either .

Comment: [Windows Feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/dotnet-35-windows) from control panel doesnt work? does system restore still working? do you have restore checkpoint(s) prior to this entire problem?

Comment: yes and it stopped working before the problem, if i would have an acceptable Restore Point i would use it . also .NET Framework doesn't show up in "Programs and Features" , so can't uninstall it either, it's installer doesn't have a "fix" button or anything similar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255550/discussion-between-ilia-and-bagus-tesa).

Answer (score 1):

solution:

- i allowed access to `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\assembly` by changing it's permissions . terminated all Window's `explorer` processes . and moved all content of the folder out to temp folder outside `%windir%` , by running `move "<<path to folder which will be moved>>" "<<path to folder to move to>>"` .

  - if the items stay within `%windir%\Microsoft.NET` they can be picked by Explorer .
- ran `sfc /SCANNOW` in Elevated Command Prompt, it restored `GAC_MSIL` and fixed 1 app .
- copied other folders back to the `assembly` and that fixed the other ones .
- #edit: i was getting problems with other apps, these are also of Windows so couldn't be reinstalled, so i had to pick such items of corrupted `GAC_MSIL` , that don't correspond by name to items which i added to GAS, and copy them back . this worked .

YEEEES!!

p.s. this won't restore .NET Assemblies which are added by installed apps, i didn't risk adding stuff from the corrupted `GAC_MSIL` , even which have explicit names . but these apps normally can handle their dependencies, and even if not, can be reinstalled .